# Remove subsubsection numbering and remove the blank space when underlining

Tags: spacing, sectioning, numbering

My question refers to removing the blank space in front of the `subsubsections` when disabling the numbering.

Concerning the way to disable the `subsubsections` numbering, there is no problem, this is what I have found:

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{}
```

Since I also wish to have them underlined, I added this to my code:

```
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\underline}
```

Everything seems to work fine, but the problem is that the underlined `subsubsections` also leaves a little space in front of them.

Here is an example:

```
\subsubsection{example}
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance for any help

[EDIT]

So, here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\underline}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{}

\begin{document}

\section{section example}

\subsection{subsection example}

\subsubsection{subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

Which outputs this:

[image]

Thank you again very much for any help

[/EDIT]

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Go ahead and post your complete (compilable) WME instead of a fragment.

Comment: What do you want subsections for?  Without numbers, presumably you don't want them in the TOC or as part of equation numbers.  You could just throw in a \par\bigskip\textbf{\Large example}\par\medskip  or something to that effect.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I don't know how I didn't of that earlier, so I did a `\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\par\bigskip\underline}` which fitted exactly my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to underline the titles. But it's your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\underline}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\section{section example}

\subsection{subsection example}

\subsubsection{subsubsection example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to the help of @John Kormylo I was able to solve my problem with:

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\par\bigskip\underline}
```

Which outputs:

[image]